# Random IO error with NAS

Tags: windows, nas

We currently have really mysterious error with our NAS (Synology DSM). We have multiple workstation with Windows 7 64 bits / Windows 8 64 bits.

In multiple program we have IO error or file not found error. It's really random. But the only workaround we found is when we open the file in Windows Explorer, the file not found disappeaer for a while.

Ex: 
-Soft01 try to open Z:\Folder\MyFile 
-Error, file not found -We open the file Z:\Folder\MyFile in Windows Explorer
-Soft01 try to open Z:\Folder\MyFile 
-It work

Anyone have an idea what can cause random IO error on a NAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be anything from the disks in the NAS to the network itself.
Is there anyway you can run a diagnostic on the NAS's disks.

If it's always the same file, I would lean towards a disk error, though if the file is of a certain size, it could be the NAS network adapter.

Also, a specific program could put a lock on a file and cause it to report an I/O error.
Are multiple instances of the same program accessing the same file when you get this error? I would heavily lean towards this explanation if if it's the program throwing a generic IO error dialog and not the OS.

Comment: It's always different file.  Some times multiple user try to access the file at the same file.  But other time it's only 1 program/1 user that try to access a file

Comment: We will try to run a diagnostic soon, I'll update my post

Comment: Update the NAS firwmare seem to have fixed the problem